# How to order posts by meta value?

Tags: order

All posts are using a custom field "deadline" (format: yyyy-mm-dd). How do I make my category page order posts by `meta_key` "deadline" and `DESC`? I use this:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { 
    $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { 
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); 
} else { 
    $paged = 1; 
}
query_posts( array( 
    'paged'    => $paged , 
    'cat'      => $category_id , 
    'meta_key' => 'deadline' , 
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value' , 
    'order'    => 'DESC' 
));
get_template_part( 'loop' );
```

but it doesn't work to order posts by `meta_value`.

Comment: Never use query_posts, it will cause problems (like breaking pagination). Use WP_Query or get_posts instead.

Comment: What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, never use `query_posts`, as it breaks a lot of stuff.  Use a filter like `pre_get_posts` instead.  The filter `pre_get_posts` allows you to edit the query before it gets executedby WP.  The following code will order by the meta value you want.  I made it so it only works on the main query of a page and with the post type `post`, but you can edit it filter it further:

```
function wpse194643_special_sort( $query ) {
    //is this the main query and is this post type of post
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_post_type( 'post' ) ) {
        //Do a meta query
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array( 'key' => 'deadline' )
        ) );
        //sort by a meta value
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse194643_special_sort' );
```

Comment: I got error message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in xxx/custom-functions.php on line 58

Comment: Fixed.  Try it now